# Generate random number of an element (rain)

Tags: javascript

I'm a new programming student and I've been stuck with an instruction for quite a while. I have to create an animation made of Nyan cats raining (in a certain direction, in a random rotation angle, etc.). I tried many things but I can't figure out how to add a random number of cats on my screen.

I tried `Math.floor(Math.random()` but I don't know how to link it to my cat.

Here's my code. It's probably not very optimized but for now the "step-by-step" writing is understandable to me.

```
<body>
    <button id="make_it_rain">Make it rain!</button>
    <img id ="cat" src="img/cat.png">
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <audio id="myAudio"> 
        <source src="audio/nyancat.ogg">
            <source src="audio/nyancat.mp3">
            </audio>

<script>

var btn = document.getElementById("make_it_rain"); 
    btn.addEventListener("click", rainCat);

// Animation starts
function rainCat()
{ 
setTimeout(animationEnd,10000);

  // Background styling 
  var background = document.getElementById("container");
  background.style.display = "block";
  document.body.appendChild(background);
  var pos_background = 0;
  setInterval(frameBackground, 100);

  // Background moves
  function frameBackground()
  {
    if (pos_background == -100) {
        pos_background = 0;
    } else {
        pos_background--;
        background.style.top = pos_background + "%"; 
        background.style.left = pos_background + "%"; 
    }
  }

  // Cat styling
  var nyanCat = document.getElementById("cat");
  nyanCat.style.display = "block";
  nyanCat.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
  document.body.appendChild(nyanCat);

  // Cat variables (position, rotate, speed)
  var pos_cat_left = 100;
  var pos_cat_top = 0;
  var rotate = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
  setInterval(oneCat, 5);

  // One cat moves
  function oneCat()
  {
    if (pos_cat_left == 100) {
        pos_cat_left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
        pos_cat_top = 0;
        rotateCat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
    } else {
        pos_cat_top = pos_cat_top + 0.5; 
        pos_cat_left = pos_cat_left + 0.5;
        nyanCat.style.top = pos_cat_top + "%"; 
        nyanCat.style.left = pos_cat_left + "%"; 
        nyanCat.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)';
    }
  }

  // Music plays
  document.getElementById('myAudio').play();
  function playAudio() { audio.play(); }
}

  // Animation stops
  function animationEnd() {
    location.reload(); 
  }

</script>


</body>
```

For now the animation works well, but how can I multiply my cats randomly so that many cats rain at the same time?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is only one cat image in your DOM, you probably have to create multiple in a loop:

```
const cats = [];

for(let count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
 const cat = document.createElement("img");

 cat.src = "./cat.png";
 cat.style.display = "block";
 cat.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";

 document.body.appendChild(cat);
 cats.push(cat);
}
```

Now that you have an array of cats, you also have to update them every tick:

```
function render() {
  for(const cat of cats) {
    // your cat update logic from oneCat()
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update); // better as a timer, as it only updates on every display rerender
}

render();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add my version of solution with cloning and rotation based on your code
please look to this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aq02wu4j/1/

the main point is using array of animation objects :

```
var btn = document.getElementById("make_it_rain"); 
    btn.addEventListener("click", rainCat);

// Animation starts
function rainCat()
{ 
setTimeout(animationEnd,1000000);

  // Background styling 
  var background = document.getElementById("container");
  background.style.display = "block";
  document.body.appendChild(background);
  var pos_background = 0;
  setInterval(frameBackground, 100);

  // Background moves
  function frameBackground()
  {
    if (pos_background == -100) {
        pos_background = 0;
    } else {
        pos_background--;
        background.style.top = pos_background + "%"; 
        background.style.left = pos_background + "%"; 
    }
  }
    var numbersOfCats = 3;
  // Cat styling
  var catsPos = {};
  for(var i = 0; i <numbersOfCats ; ++i) {
  catsPos[i] = {};
  catsPos[i].nyanCat = $("#cat").clone()[0];
  catsPos[i].nyanCat.style.display = "block";
  catsPos[i].nyanCat.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
  document.body.appendChild(catsPos[i].nyanCat);

  // Cat variables (position, rotate, speed)
  catsPos[i].pos_cat_left = 0;
  catsPos[i].pos_cat_top = 0;
  catsPos[i].rotate = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
    runNewCat(i);

}
function runNewCat(i) {
setInterval(function() { 
  oneCat(i)
  }, 10);
}

  // One cat moves
  function oneCat(i)
  {
   var catData = catsPos[i];
    if (catData.pos_cat_left >= 100) {
        catData.pos_cat_left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
        catData.pos_cat_top = 0;
        catData.rotateCat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
        catData.rotate =45;
    } else {
            catData.rotate +=5;
        catData.pos_cat_top = catData.pos_cat_top + 0.5; 
        catData.pos_cat_left = catData.pos_cat_left + 0.5;
        catData.nyanCat.style.top = catData.pos_cat_top + "px"; 
        catData.nyanCat.style.left = catData.pos_cat_left + "px"; 
        catData.nyanCat.style.transform = 'rotate(' + catData.rotate + 'deg)';
    }
  }

  // Music plays
  document.getElementById('myAudio').play();
  function playAudio() { audio.play(); }
}

  // Animation stops
  function animationEnd() {
    location.reload(); 
  }
```